# How do you scale image to fit size of the paper?

Tags: beamer, graphics, floats, scaling

[image]

I am making a presentation on `beamer` and I am struggling with image I don't understand: `scale;line width;text height` on positioning the image. Especially when I add caption it gets messed up. How do I position it to occupy exactly the same space. I understand this tools are the most handy if one figures it out.

Here is my code

```
\begin{frame}{Mechanical Resonant Circuit}
  \begin{figure}[ht] 
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.6\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{image/msd2.pdf} 
    \caption{Mechanical circuit of a loudspeaker} 
    \vspace{4ex}
  \end{minipage}%%
  \pause
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.6\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{image/rcm2.pdf}
    \caption{Mobility analogy} 
    \vspace{4ex}
  \end{minipage}%%
  \pause

  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.3\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.1]{image/Impedanc_analogy.pdf} 
    \caption{Impedance analogy} 
    \vspace{4ex}
  \end{minipage}\hfill
  \pause
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.1]{image/velocity.png} 
    \caption{Velocity response} 
    \vspace{4ex}
  \end{minipage}  
  \end{figure} 
\end{frame}
```

Comment: \linewidth and \textwidth are almost but not quite the same.  In landscape, \linewidth has the width and \textheight=\textwidth.  If \leftskip and \rightskip are nonzero (inside a list for example) then \linewidth =\textwidth - \leftskip - \rightskip.

Comment: BTW, I would remove the \vspace{4ex} and put a \vfill between the two rows.  That will use whatever space is available (if any).

Comment: \Vfill works like a charm but anyway what are those number [0.3 \linewidth] [0.5\linewidth]? and sometime [0.5\textheight]what is the difference it is killing me by changing those values emperically

Comment: Well, the two sum of the widths should not exceed \linewidth, and the sum of the heights plus the heights of the captions should not exceed \textheight (or whatever beamer uses for the frame height).  Worst case, experiment with \rule to see how much space is actually available.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation so what is is the maximum \linewidth and \textheight? And how do you use \rule?

Answer (score 5):

Especially if you have pictures of different sizes, I find using `scale` very difficult. Either determine the size of an image by giving its height or width, e.g.

```
\includegraphics[width=...]{...}
```

or

```
\includegraphics[height=...]{...}
```

This can either be done in absolute values like `width=3cm` or relative values `width=.33\textwidth`, which makes the image third the size of the line. This way has the advantage, that you can either make images of one row to have the same height or images below each other to have the same height.

Now to align the images and their captions, I normally find it easier to place them inside `columns` instead of `minipage`s, but that is really just a matter if tast. The following code divides a frame into two columns, each of `.45\textwidth`. In the first row the images each occupy half the width of a column, in the second row they have the same height.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Mechanical Resonant Circuit}
    \begin{columns}[T]
        \begin{column}{.45\textwidth}
            \begin{figure}
                \includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{example-grid-100x100bp} 
                \caption{Mechanical circuit of a loudspeaker}
            \end{figure}
        \end{column}
        \pause
        \begin{column}{.45\textwidth}
            \begin{figure}
                \includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{example-grid-100x100bp} 
                \caption{Mobility analogy}
            \end{figure}
        \end{column}        
    \end{columns}
    \pause
    \vfill
    \begin{columns}[T]
        \begin{column}{.45\textwidth}
            \begin{figure}
                \includegraphics[height=.25\textheight]{example-image-16x9} 
                \caption{Impedance analogy}
            \end{figure}
        \end{column}
        \pause
        \begin{column}{.45\textwidth}
            \begin{figure}
                \includegraphics[height=.25\textheight]{example-image-9x16} 
                \caption{Velocity response}
            \end{figure}
        \end{column}        
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Cool, thanks i get the idea, but if the width of the column is .45\textwidth how can the image be .5\textwidth isn't it supposed to be less then width of column.

Comment: @ShashankThapa the `.5\textwidth` referens to the width of the column, so 50% of 45% makes a width of 0.225\textwidth, roughly a quarter of the page.

Comment: ah i get it now. Merci.

Comment: @ShashankThapa de rien !

Comment: Is there a corresponding height-based metric when using `\begin{block}` that will constrain the image's height so that it lies between the top of the block and the bottom of the slide?

Answer (score 1):

In answer to your questions about `\linewidth`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\newsavebox{\tempbox}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{size values}
paper width = \the\paperwidth\par
paper height = \the\paperheight\par
text width = \the\textwidth\par
text height = \the\textheight\par
line width = \the\linewidth\par
\savebox{\tempbox}{\fbox{test area}}
\usebox{\tempbox}\par
width of test area = \the\wd\tempbox\par
height of test area = \the\ht\tempbox\hfill (distance above baseline)\par
depth of test area = \the\dp\tempbox\hfill (distance below baseline)\par
total height = \the\dimexpr \ht\tempbox + \dp\tempbox\relax\par
% \relax terminiates the \dimexpr if not otherwise stopped
baseline spacing = \the\baselineskip
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{text area}
\rule{\textwidth}{\textheight}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]